# "Despite the fish begging me for mercy, I still ate it." "Despite the fish that begged me for mercy, I still ate it."

Tags: difference

I wonder if these two sentences mean the same thing.

> Despite the fish begging me for mercy, I still ate it.

> Despite the fish that begged me for mercy, I still ate it.

my guess is that in the first sentence emphasis is in "begging me for mercy" and "the fish" is put there only to show its subject ,so it is different from the second one which suggests that I ate it in spite of the fish of such kind.
or maybe there are more than one ways to understand the first sentence?

Comment: It is unclear what *it* refers to in the second sentence. Perhaps a fish is begging you to spare (not eat) your spaghetti. *It* in the first sentence clearly refers to the fish that is doing the begging.

Comment: The "correct" position of ***that*** in the second version is *Despite **that** the fish begged me for mercy...* That's a dated / literary construction that you should avoid in that"bare" form today, but it's fine (if a bit "wordy") to say *Despite **the fact that** the fish begged me for mercy...*

Comment: @DM: I don't think either of OP's alternatives has any different implications for deciding what the (ambiguous) reference of ***it*** might be.

Comment: I think I can see it now.  These two sentences,not definitely but very likely, have the same effect in listeners' mind while the meanings are not exactly identical. My question was first inspired by a commercial saying "getting tired of you and your friends being considered...."  and it seemed wrong to  substitute the participle with an adjective clause.